# Determine the convergence of infinite series $1-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3} +\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How shall I determine whether the series
 $$1-1+
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots$$ is convergent or divergent?
Please help?

Comment: Hint: Write out the sequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: For large $n$ partial sums are arbitrary small.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $S_n$ denote the sum of $n$ terms of the series.

$S_n = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } n \textrm{ is even} \\ 
\frac{1}{k} & \mbox{if } n \textrm{ is odd }, n = 2k - 1. \end{cases}$

The series converges iff $S_n$ converges as a sequence. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

What do you have?

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}-\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$

or

$$=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{ \left\lfloor(n+1)/2\right\rfloor}$$

---

Regardless, the partial sums converge to $0$.

---

The second series I have above, 
$$S=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{ \left\lfloor(n+1)/2\right\rfloor}$$

For all $n$ even, we have $S=0$, for odd we have $n= \frac{1}{ \left\lfloor(n+1)/2\right\rfloor}$, but this is now a sequence, not a harmonic series. The series hits $0$ every even, and then goes to this sequence.

Comment: Looking at the expression, I can say it converges to zero as the limit of Sn exists as a real number 0, but if I look closely it is the difference of two P-series with p=1, which means the difference of two divergent series. Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: @user46044 Does my comment help(added to answer)?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:The $n^{th}$ and $(n+1)^{th}$ term cancel each other out.
(n odd)